# Repeated games with observable actions

Tags: game-theory

I'm going to hold a lecture in a study circle about Repeated games and observable actions and also a little about Repeated games with imperfect public information.
We are following the book of Fudenberg and Tirole.
Anyone has any good exercises so solve on those concepts?
Not to hard to solve, maximum a few hours for a graduate student.
Thanks.